# in java is the name of a method a string?

Tags: java, methods

in java is the name of a method a string? why or why not?

so if i have something like:

```
public static int METHODNAME (some parameters or not) 
{
something to do ;
}
```

is METHODNAME a string?

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit.

Comment: I take it to mean "is the name stored in memory as a string"

Comment: @David: because it's almost impossible to understand it unless reading Bob's comment.

Comment: it seems pretty straitforward to me.

Comment: @David, well, at least 5 people disagree (4 down-voters an myself), or disagreed with the way you first asked your question. Your current question can be answered with a simple: "no, METHODNAME is not a String".

Comment: @David, if METHODNAME is a String then, it should have been, public static int "METHODNAME"(...), which is illegal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's a symbol. However, via [reflection](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/index.html) you can look up the method using a string version of its name if that's useful.

Comment: "it's a symbol" - Can you give a proof link?

Answer (score 3):

If you asking whether or not you can do: "methodName"() or $command() and have it execute the method named as you can in PhP.  The answer is no.

If you're asking whether or not the method name is stored as a String somewhere, the answer is yes.  You can access it using reflection.  For example:

```
Method[] methods = Double.class.getMethods();
for(Method m : methods) {
    System.out.println("Method: "+m.getName());
}
```

In reference to your edit.  No it is not a String in that context.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, David:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

Class C = Class.forName("yourClass");
Method methods[] = C.getDeclaredMethods();
for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) 
{  
               Method m = methlist[i];
               System.out.println(m.getName());
}
```

And it would eventually print out "METHODNAME," as a string, if METHODNAME was in yourClass.